# "Reutilización" de convertView en adapter de listview repite elementos

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, baseadapter

Tengo un listview con un Adapter propio (extends BaseAdapter). He leído que en el método getView se puede aprovechar el parámetro View para aumentar el rendimiento ya que reutiliza la vista ya calculada (por ejemplo https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render?hl=es-419) .
Mi problema viene que los primeros items se cargan correctamente pero cuando haces scroll ahí donde deberían aparecer los nuevos items se empiezan a repetir los primeros elementos (por ejemplo en lugar de mostrar el elemento 11 muestra el 1, en lugar del 12 muestra el 2...). De hecho a partir de ahí si empiezas a subir y a bajar con el scroll parece que se lía aún más la cosa.
En principio debería ser algo tan fácil como:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v;
        if(convertView == null){
            //Inflamos la vista con nuestro propio layout
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
            v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, viewGroup, false);

            final DBLata lataActual = latas.get(position);

            TextView textView = v.findViewById(R.id.marca);
            textView.setText(lataActual.marca+" "+lataActual.color);
            textView.setTag(lataActual.id);
            ....
        }else{
            v = convertView;
        }
        return v;
```

¿Alguna idea de por dónde van los tiros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes razón cuando dices que con ayudas en el rendimiento, pero en el código lo que haces es devolver el objeto ya creado, es decir si un view en la posición 1 se ha creado, cuando llega a la posición 11, como ya no es null, devuelves el mismo elemento. si quieres que ese elemento en posición 11 devuelva los datos que corresponden a la posición 11, deberías setear los datos que corresponden a la posición 11. **Solo los datos** porque **la vista (view) ya fue creada**.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v;
    if(convertView == null){
        //Inflamos la vista con nuestro propio layout
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, viewGroup, false);
        ....
    }else{
        v = convertView;
    }

    final DBLata lataActual = latas.get(position);

    TextView textView = v.findViewById(R.id.marca);
    textView.setText(lataActual.marca+" "+lataActual.color);
    textView.setTag(lataActual.id);
    return v;
 }
```

Comment: Pufff, tienes toda la razón... Típica chorrada que cuando llevas varias horas no la ves hasta que alguien te lo resuelve en 0 coma... Gracias!